# Google Map: Link to the map according to feature type

Tags: google-maps-api-3, hyperlink, marker

I have a google Map with markers on a webpage.
Each marker has a unique feature position and type

This is the scenario I would like to put in place:

- On another webpage I have static links to different markers of the map.
- If you click on one of those links, you are directed to the map in which, one of these markers is centered (and its info window open).

But the markers latitude and longitude might change while the links will never change.

This means, I need the links not to use latitude and longitude info but markers feature type instead (which are remain the same).

How can I do that?

Here is my sample google Map script so far:

```
<script>

function initMap() {
    var mapDiv = document.getElementById('map');
    var map = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv, {
        center: {lat: 48.85639, lng: 2.33625}, // default centering
        zoom: 18,
        styles: 
        [
            {featureType: 'poi',stylers: [{ visibility: 'off' }]},
            {featureType: 'transit.station',stylers: [{ visibility: "off" }]}
        ]
    });

    var features = [
      {position: new google.maps.LatLng(48.85659, 2.33555),type: 'markerone'},
      {position: new google.maps.LatLng(48.85619, 2.33695),type: 'markertwo'}           
    ];

    var icons = {
          'markerone': {icon: 'icon_one.png'},
          'markertwo': {icon: 'icon_two.png'}
    };

    var contents= {
          'markerone': {text: 'Content 1'},
          'markertwo': {text: 'Content 2'}
    };

    for (var i = 0, feature; feature = features[i]; i++) 
    {
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: feature.position,
            icon: icons[feature.type].icon,
            map: map
        });

        var content = contents[feature.type].text;

        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow()

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker,'mouseover', (function(marker,content,infowindow){ 
            return function() {
                infowindow.setContent(content);
                infowindow.open(map,marker);
            };
        })(marker,content,infowindow)); 

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker,'mouseout', (function(marker,content,infowindow){ 
            return function() {
                infowindow.close(map,marker);
            };
        })(marker,content,infowindow));
    }        

}
</script>
```

In this sample, I have to markers.
One has a feature type of "markerone" and the second is "markertwo".

How can I set my links to redirect and center the map around a specific marker in this kind of fashion:
http://www.mywebsite.com/mymap.php?myvariable=markertwo

Thank you.

Comment: You mean like this: http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_MW_example_linktomarker.html?id=Marker%20Two

Answer (score 0):

First you would have to get the parameters. The example below gets all parameters and put them into an array. There you can search for your certain paramater like "markerType" and check if it's given or not. If not you have to perform a default action, otherwise you can handle the certain markerType like finding the correct marker, setting the map center to it and open the corrosponding infoWindow.

You just have to call the `focusMarkerType`-method onload of your page.

```
function getSearchParameters() {
      var prmstr = window.location.search.substr(1);
      return prmstr != null && prmstr != "" ? transformToAssocArray(prmstr) : {};
}

function transformToAssocArray( prmstr ) {
    var params = {};
    var prmarr = prmstr.split("&");
    for ( var i = 0; i < prmarr.length; i++) {
        var tmparr = prmarr[i].split("=");
        params[tmparr[0]] = tmparr[1];
    }
    return params;
}

function focusMarkerType(){
  var params = getSearchParameters();
  if(params.markerType!=null){
     //Handling the certain marker type
     var found = false;
     for (var i = 0, feature; feature = features[i]; i++) {
         if (feature.type == params.markerType) {
            found = true;
            map.setCenter(feature.position);
            //more...
            break;
         }
     }
     if (!found) {
         console.log("unknown type")
     }
  }else{
     //Handling default behaviour if no marker type is given
  }
}
```